# How to paste multiple email addresss into iPhone mail To: field?

Tags: ios, mobile-mail

If I copy and paste multiple email address into iPad email's To: field, e.g.:

```
a@b.com, b@c.com, c@d.com
```

the mail app will consider it as one address, not three. Is there a way to copy and paste multiple email address in a new mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for mail to distinguish them as separate addresses, they must be formatted as follows before pasting:

```
<a@b.com>, <b@c.com>, <c@d.com>
```